# How to Get Updated Fields Using Simple-Salesforce

Tags: rest-api, update

I am trying to get **only** the updated fields data in a record using [simple-salesforce](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce).

With the SObject Get Updated API, I can only get a list of record `ids` which get updated in a given time period, but it does not tell me which `fields` in each record get changed.

Is there any way I can know which fields in a record get updated so that I can retrieve the updated value using the [simple-salesforce](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce) APIs?

Comment: Is the field history enabled for these fields?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a update trigger and get all the fields on the object and check each value on the field with reference to trigger.old and trigger.new. Below is a sample code :

```
    if(Trigger.isUpdate)
        {
           // Gets all the available fields from the required object.
            Obj__c object = new Obj__c();   
            Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> mapFields = Schema.SObjectType.Obj__c.fields.getMap(); 

            for(Obj__c o : trigger.new)
            {
                Obj__c oldObj = trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id);

                for (String str : mapFields.keyset()) 
                { 
                    try 
                    { 
                        if(o.get(str) != oldObj.get(str))
                        { 
                            System.Debug('Field changed: ' + str + ' Old Value: ' + oldObj.get(str) + ' New Value:' + o.get(str)); 
                        } 
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    { 
                        System.Debug('Error: ' + e); 
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't tell which fields are modified (except for those that are [tracked](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tracking_field_history.htm)). Your best option is to describe the object and retrieve all of the data, or at least the fields you're interested in. This is a bit of a waste of bandwidth, but it's the only option you really have currently.